# Squeeze Principle

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive integers and let $f$ be a function on the integers. Suppose that for each $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ there exists an integer $L$ such that for every $n \geq L$ we have
$$
\epsilon f(n) \leq a_n \leq f(n).
$$
Is is true that we can find an $L_1$ such that $a_n = f(n)$ for every $n \geq L_1$? Thanks!

Comment: Clearly $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily close to $1$, but not exactly $1$; hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take, for example $a_n=n$ and $f(n)= n+1$

Comment: How is it that $\epsilon (n+1) \leq n$?

Comment: if $$n\ge \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}=L$$
then $(1-\epsilon)n\ge \epsilon$ and $n\ge (n+1)\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(n) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the sequence $a_n = n-1$.

For any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, set $L = \left\lceil\dfrac{1}{1-\epsilon}\right\rceil$. Then, $\epsilon f(n) = \epsilon n \le n-1 \le n = f(n)$ for all $n \ge L$.

However, there is no $L_1$ such that $a_n = n - 1 = n$ for all $n \ge L$.

Comment: $a_n$ must be a positive integer.

Comment: Good catch. I'll just multiply everything by $n$.

Comment: That pretty much makes it the same example Mher had already posted.

Comment: I'm sorry but how is it that $\epsilon (n + 1) \leq n$?

Comment: If $n \ge L \ge \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$, then $n-\epsilon n \ge 1$, i.e. $\epsilon n \le n-1$. Also, if $\epsilon = 0.99$, then $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} = 100$ which is way bigger than $2$.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed right after :) and deleted it, oops.

Comment: This counterexample supposes that $a_n \neq f(n)$. How about if we do not assume this? The sequence $\{a_n \}$ that I have actually hits the value of $f(n)$ sometimes. Thanks guys!

Comment: How does that help? Let $a_n = n-1$ for odd $n$ and $a_n = n$ for even $n$. Use $f(n) = n$ again.